# Samsung Galaxy Gio isn't being recognized via USB

Tags: usb, samsung, connection-issues, windows

I've been using Samsung Galaxy Gio for about 3 years, I have no problem in connecting my phone to my old PC. But I've just move to the new laptop, now I can't make my laptop to recognize my device.

But now I use USBDeview to view USB devices connected to my computer, I see this:

[image: Image from USBDeview]

which clearly says that the device is successfully connected to the computer.

I also hearing "Device connected" sound effect multiple times after I plugged in the device.

I have Samsung USB Driver version 1.5.33.0 installed. (Downloaded from XDA Developers)

How can I fix this?

Regards,
Sarun

Comment: Does the phone give any type of notification? Like MTP or something as indication?

Comment: Usually in my old computer, when the device is successfully connected, there will be a notification "USB Connected". But on this new laptop, none.